# What is actually quoted?

Tags: shell

```
1.ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-72:~$ echo {\""date\"" : \""`date`\""}
{"date" : "Sun Sep 12 04:52:13 UTC 2021"}
```

```
2.ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-72:~$ echo {"\"date\"" : "\"`date`\""}
{"date" : "Sun Sep 12 04:52:38 UTC 2021"}
```

both are generating same output .
I want to understand  about first statement how it is escaping second double quotes even it was placed at starting not preceded with double quotes which I want to escape .I mean as follows

```
echo {\""date it should be like second statement echo{"\"date .
```

how come it consider inner double quote need to escape .

Comment: Ask *"What is actually quoted?"* The second is correct (balanced), but the first provides the same results. Break it down. In the first case you have `\"` (the first escaped quote -- `echo` will output `"` ) followed by `"date\""`. So `echo` will output `date"`. Combine that with the first escaped quote and you have `"date"`. The fact it raises the question shows why the second (balanced) method is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin This is helpful

Comment: I suggest using `jq` to generate JSON on the fly so you don't have to worry as much about properly escaping everything that needs to be: `jq -n --arg date "$(date)" '{date: $date}'` (This works properly even if `date`'s (Or whatever other command) output has quotes, newlines, or other special characters in it.)